# Does Google Cloud Storage streaming transfer support simultaneous read / writes?

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-storage

Is it possible to write data with one process, and in the same time read with same process or another one, on same or different GCE machine?

The API is doesn't seem to cover this one:

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#streaming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. An object is not visible for reads until the writer finishes writing and finalizes the object.

Depending on your specific use case, you might be able to use [composite objects](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects) to achieve what you need. For example, instead of writing to one large object, you could write smaller chunks of the object to individual objects, then compose them together into a larger object when finished. This would allow a reader to read each component after it's been written.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. What about media file which I need to be readable almost immediately, is there any suggestion how to make it readable at same time? Or the only way is to keep it locally then upload in background?

Comment: What do you mean by immediately? If you mean immediately after it's written, GCS is strongly consistent, so it's available right away from anywhere in the world.

Comment: To clarify, I need to allow access to file while it's being written. Will GCS allow this in any way, or the best idea is to implement an access layer, accessing the file transparently both on local and GSC storage?

Comment: No other way I can think of